# VR indication using Oculus Quest2 and three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality, oculus, webxr

I am planning to use Oculus and three.js to display VR. I thought I would check the operation with the official sample first.

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=vr#webxr_vr_ballshooter

I expected to be able to access the following official sample on my PC and press enter to see VR on my USB connected Quest2. However, the screen on the PC is split (presumably for 3D rendering) and the Quest2 screen still says Now Loading.
Is it not possible to do what I expect? Or is there something I need to do? Please help me.

Trying official tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Self solved. I had General->Unknown Source and Beta->Developer Runtime enabled in the Oculus app on my desktop PC, but I also had Beta->Public Test Channel enabled. I also did the latest software update.